# How to use the current excel sheet to write value to a cell. C#

Tags: c#

So the following code basically create an empty excel file (which I named "demo.xls") and writes a string value of "Text" into cell number A1. I removed all the rest of the code, I just want to know if I already have an existing excel file (let's name it "exist.xls").

How can I change the first line of the code so it will just use the existing excel file("exist.xls") instead of creating a new one ("demo.xls") and write a string value of "Text" into cell number A1?

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("demo.xls", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
WriteToCell writer = new WriteToCell(stream);
writer.BeginWrite();

writer.WriteCell(1, 1, "Text");

writer.EndWrite();
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("demo.xls",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

With

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream((File.Exists("exists.xls") ? "exists.xls" : "demo.xls"),FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

Note - I haven't tested this.